# What is the proper way to use the Months view in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use the month view on [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-12">
  <input id="portalDownloadMonth" type="text" readonly class="form-control pl-3" data-date-format="mm-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="months" placeholder="Mes" required>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript

```
$('#portalDownloadMonth').datepicker({
  format: "mm-yyyy",
  viewMode: "months", 
  minViewMode: "months",
});
```

But this is not working at all, the input shows the day view

[image]

Can someone tell me what I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the bootstrap-datepicker from the tag you provided on the question, you need to use:

```
format: "M yyyy",
```

Example snippet:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "M yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Thank you dude, I was really having a bad time on this one... the previous devs did not even pointed out which package nor version they were using